# Edit RESTAdapter url for API end point

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an api endpoint that requires a `/` at the end of it, but Ember does not add the `/`.  Is there a way to edit the URL that the RESTAdapter creates so that it adds this slash?

Currently the URL ember sends is `http://www.myapi.com/v1/roles`

I need the URL to look like this:  `http://www.myapi.com/v1/roles/`

Here is my current ApplicationAdapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajaxError: function() {
    console.log('error');
  },

  host: 'http://www.myapi.com',

  namespace: 'v1'

});
```

Here is my router:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('role');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to override the `buildURL` function on your ApplicationAdapter to append the trailing slash. You can just call the default `buildURL` that DS.RESTAdapter provides and then append the slash.

Here's what the code will look like:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajaxError: function() {
    console.log('error');
  },

  host: 'http://www.myapi.com',

  namespace: 'v1',

  buildURL: function(type, id, record) {
    //call the default buildURL and then append a slash
    return this._super(type, id, record) + '/';
  }

});
```

Here's the [documentation for buildURL](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL).

Comment: Thank you!  I still am not clear on what _super() is but I did not try calling it when I was looking at buildURL earlier.  Thank you!!!